# Search the name of a country for a game

Tags: c, game-development

Not sure if anyone knows the game atlas but basically the game starts with one person giving the name of a country and the next guy gives another country starting with the last letter of the previous person's country and so on.

The last letter matching part is done but I just need to make sure that whatever the name of the country given is a valid one and has not been used before in the game. Can someone give me some ideas?

P.S. this was a small beginner project I decided to make so the code is c

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. Please go through the Help Center, how to ask and a tour of the site.

Comment: What specific problem do you have? Presumably you have a list of valid countries in a data structure. If so, just search for the given county in that list. If not found it is invalid. If found it is valid. Also remove it from the list after found so that it can't be used again. Can't be any more specific since your question is too broad.

Comment: create a `struct Country { char name[256]; bool used;};`, find a list of all the countries somewhere and read that into an array of `struct Country`s. When someone names a country, flip the `used` to true.

Comment: @justanotherguy new here and i skipped the tour so that was a mistake

Comment: on the outside, if the country name was valid I wanted the game to proceed as normal but if the name is not an actual country name that exists then the game should stop. I was not sure how to achieve that but @yano gave the idea to make an array. But if I simply declare an array containing the names of all countries that would consume quite a lot of memory. so I was looking for better ideas

Comment: unless you're working on an embedded system with _very_ limited resources or some academic exercise to limit your memory footprint, don't worry about it. A google search says there's 195 countries in the world. Let's be _very_ conservative and say each country name averages 64 bytes .. that's ~12.1k. That's nothing, even for an embedded system. Your typical mp3 or JPEG is 4-5MB, over 330x bigger. A standard PC now ships with gigabytes of memory, even the lower end ones. Your OS won't break a sweat.

Comment: here you go, found this [country list](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kalinchernev/486393efcca01623b18d/raw/daa24c9fea66afb7d68f8d69f0c4b8eeb9406e83/countries) on github. I copied and pasted this list to a text file .. the file size (with Windows line endings) is a whopping 2037 _bytes_ (sense my sarcasm). Compare that to your typical Word, Excel, etc file. Compare that to the file size of your executable. Unless you're coding on a machine from 1966, you have no reason to worry about excessive memory consumption.

Comment: if you're hellbent on limiting data memory consumption, then you're going to have to implement some kind of hash table/compression algorithm that maps a country name to a smaller unique data value. 195 countries will easily fit into an `unsigned char`, which typically holds values up to 255, so certainly doable. Note that this will increase your code size, which I'd guess would negate the gains made in less data storage for overall memory consumption. IMO such a design solely to limit memory usage is complete overkill, far more complicated, and serves no practical advantage.

Comment: well, then I guess I don't need to worry about memory then. anyways thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

For the best learning experience, you could not look at the code and just the instructions. But, it's fine if you use the code too :)

You can make an array of all the countries you want to support (I don't know how to get them all)

```
static char Countries[NumCountries][MaxCountryLength] =
{
    "United States of America\0",
    "Canada\0",
    ...
};
```

Then you can make another 2d char array of the same size as well as an `unsigned int` for how many countries have been successfully guessed

```
static unsigned int CountriesUsed;
static char UsedCountries[NumCountries][MaxCountryLength] =
{
    "Mexico\0",
    "Greenland\0",
    ...
};
```

Then, when someone guesses, loop through the first array to see if it is the same string. If it is, check the next array up until `CountriesUsed` to see if it is in there. If so, set `UsedCountries[CountriesUsed]` to the country. If anything fails, print messages accordingly. Make sure to increment `CountriesUsed`!

```
const char *Guess = ;// Your guess code
for(unsigned int AllCountryIndex = 0;
    AllCountryIndex < NumCountries;
    ++AllCountryIndex)
{
    if(strcmp(Guess, (const char *)Countries[AllCountryIndex]) == 0)
    {
        for(unsigned int GuessedCountriesIndex;
            GuessedCountryIndex < UsedCountries;
            ++GuessedCountryIndex)
        {
            if(strcmp(Guess, (const char *)UsedCountries[GuessedCountryIndex]) == 0)
            {
                printf("Your guess was already guessed");
            }
            else
            {
                // NOTE(vedbanerjee): Guess was correct
                ++CountriesUsed;
                UsedCountries[CountriesUsed] = Guess;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Your guess is not a country");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: What's with the `\0`s in the country name array? They're not needed

Comment: @Shawn it was just an extra precaution, I didn't have time to test this

Comment: thanks for the code but how do i get the names of the countries because simply making an array is gonna consume alot of memory

Comment: You may also use a map with the field isUsed. That'll reduce memory by half